# Memory coalescing and transaction

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

After reading about the topic,  I have 2 questions related to Global Memory coalescing access:

1- I read that one requirement for Memory coalescing is that  words accessed by the threads must be 4, 8, or 16 byte but apparently this is valid only for device with compute capability less than 1.3. Is that right? for the latter device (>=1.3), a thread can even access one or 2 bytes and have a successful coalesced memory access

2- Will it matter (time mainly)  if a (half) warp Global Memory access generates a 128-byte instead of 64-byte memory transaction because  of the words misalignment and what about the extra data transferred, will it be discarded by the system?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1) You can access the data any way you want on later devices, but the performance will still be poor if you request a data segment that is narrow, i.e. you will not achieve the full memory bandwidth of your GPU.

2) This again depends on the overall scheme of you code. Generally, the improvement in later version of CUDA was that non-aligned reads/writes did not result in abysmal performance, but resulted in e.g. 2 write commands being issues instead of one.

Think of it like putting people on a bus. If you can fill your whole crowd into a single bus with one destination, you get better efficiency than using two buses that are only half filled.

So yes, it will matter, but depending on whether you are memory or compute bound, it will matter differently.

Arranging your read/write patterns to utilize the full bandwidth have given me the last 20-30% performance in many applications.

/Henrik